# Java array algorithm, error with swapping shuffle type from an "in-shuffle" to "out-shuffle"

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, shuffle

I'm trying to duplicate the following while loop but differing in the way they both interleave my "cards".

Here's my current while loop that works, my goal is to remake this loop but reverse the order of both card_force arrays:

```
while (index >= 0) {

        card_force[index--] = bottom_half[j--];
        card_force[index--] = top_half[i--];
}
```

Here's the while loop that I want to make:

```
while (index >= 0) {
        card_force[index--] = top_half[i--];    
        card_force[index--] = bottom_half[j--];

}
```

However, if both loops exist, the original loop works but the second while loop doesn't work at all, resulting in returning "null" on 52 lines. Where I need it to return card 27, then card 1, then card 26, then card 2, and so on and so on.

I'm having an immense amount of trouble with what seems to be a simple fix.

Here's my current code:

```
        String[] card_force = new String[52];
        String[] card_force2 = new String[52];
        int i = top_half.length - 1;
        int j = bottom_half.length - 1;
        int index = 51;


        // Card out shuffle
        while (index >= 0) {

        card_force[index--] = bottom_half[j--];
        card_force[index--] = top_half[i--];  
        }
        // Card in shuffle
        while (index >= 0) {
        card_force2[index--] = top_half[i--];
       card_force2[index--] = bottom_half[j--];
        }


        // Card out shuffle print
        System.out.println("\nCard Shuffle:\n");
        for (String card_force1 : card_force) {
           System.out.println(card_force1);
        }


        // Card in shuffle print
        for (String card_force1 : card_force2) {
           System.out.println(card_force1);
        }


}
```

When the code runs, it returns the following result:

```
Card Shuffle:

Card number 1: King of Clubs
Card number 27: 10 of Spades
Card number 2: Jack of Clubs
Card number 28: King of Diamonds
Card number 3: 6 of Diamonds
Card number 29: 5 of Diamonds
Card number 4: Queen of Hearts
Card number 30: 4 of Hearts
Card number 5: 5 of Clubs
Card number 31: Queen of Diamonds
Card number 6: Ace of Hearts
Card number 32: 7 of Diamonds
Card number 7: 3 of Hearts
Card number 33: 9 of Hearts
Card number 8: 2 of Hearts
Card number 34: 10 of Diamonds
Card number 9: 10 of Clubs
Card number 35: Jack of Diamonds
Card number 10: 2 of Spades
Card number 36: 2 of Diamonds
Card number 11: 9 of Clubs
Card number 37: 2 of Clubs
Card number 12: 8 of Spades
Card number 38: 4 of Spades
Card number 13: 7 of Spades
Card number 39: Ace of Diamonds
Card number 14: 8 of Clubs
Card number 40: 9 of Spades
Card number 15: Jack of Hearts
Card number 41: 6 of Clubs
Card number 16: 3 of Diamonds
Card number 42: 7 of Hearts
Card number 17: 6 of Hearts
Card number 43: King of Hearts
Card number 18: 4 of Clubs
Card number 44: Ace of Clubs
Card number 19: 3 of Spades
Card number 45: 8 of Hearts
Card number 20: Ace of Spades
Card number 46: 5 of Hearts
Card number 21: 10 of Hearts
Card number 47: Jack of Spades
Card number 22: Queen of Clubs
Card number 48: 9 of Diamonds
Card number 23: Queen of Spades
Card number 49: 8 of Diamonds
Card number 24: 7 of Clubs
Card number 50: 5 of Spades
Card number 25: 4 of Diamonds
Card number 51: 6 of Spades
Card number 26: King of Spades
Card number 52: 3 of Clubs
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: Can you clean up this code a little so it doesn't include things that are commented off, and just shows off either the working or the failing case? We can be trusted to swap two lines around, but as is this is way more code than necessary, in a haphazard style. Clean up the indents, throw away comments, don't duplicate in a way that makes the code unrunnable, and now you'll have good code for others to look at.

Comment: the second `while` loop uses the same `index` var which was fully consumed by the first `while` loop. So the second while loop will never be executed and `card_force2` never assigned any value, it's just an array with 52 elements never assigned any value to each element, thus, all 52 elements are `null`. Either reset `index` to 51, or just use `for` loops

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans Sorry, new about here, and in a frenzy to say the least lol. Hoping this will do

Comment: I suggest reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: @BrógánMcShane: no, now you've made the code even less runnable. Please make sure it's in [mcve] form (e.g. people copy-paste your code, and have it pass `javac` without having to change a single thing, with it then running when invoked). Also, you're _still_ showing both cases, which makes no sense: why would you expect that second while loop to work at all if you're not resetting any of the indices?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the value of `index` before the second loop. The first loop stops when `index` is `-1`, and that value is still the same when the second loop checks it. As a result, the second loop never even runs.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your answer and add the OP's code with your corrections to it.